# Limiting Views diplays to a role — two displays are stuck together

Tags: views, users

I have a View with two displays, one for role1 and one for role2. When I set the access control for the first display to role1 and save the View, then set the access control for the second display to role2, it changes the first display to only be accessible to role2 as well. Have I encountered a bug, or could there be some set of configuration options causing this?

Answer (score 2):

When you set the persmissions for a display, the following popup box shows up

[image: view access popop]

below the title, there's an option that allows you to change the access restrictions to "All displays" or "This page(override)"

Comment: Yep, that is what I did prior to encountering this problem.

Comment: I did test the same earlier today and it worked for me. or may be another way would be to use page manager ?

Comment: Okay, I think this indicates that the answer to my question is that I've encountered a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a bug in Views. Here is the workaround that worked for me:

1. Edit both of the displays and change "This page (override)" to "All Displays".
2. Set one of them to the way you want it.
3. Edit the other display and change it back to "This page (override)".
4. Set that one the way you want it.

It seems to happen that a display cloned from another display confuses Views, but this fixed it for me.